# How to assign the same point to duplicate records in ArcMap geocoder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding

What I am trying to accomplish is to geocode a long list of addresses by assigning the point manually. The problem is that there are many duplicates which can not be removed. Therefore, I need to assign the same point to several duplicates causing the overlapping problem!

A quick discussion with my colleagues brought to my attention that this problem is an old problem non solved by any updates from ESRI. I am using ArcMap 10.2 and I was wondering if there is any way to get a shortcut on this problem even with a python script or else. 
[image]

Comment: Each row has it's own type of a service. The repeated addresses have multiple services activated at the same home so that is why I can not remove nor concatenate.

Comment: I dont know anything about geocoding but if the output is a point fc of matching adresses etc. you could try: Remove all fields but the adresses, create a new field holding the complete adress, create the same field in your list, do a one to many join points-complete list on the created adress fields, export as a new feature class. You then should have duplicate points for duplicate adresses

Comment: Thank you BERA. It makes sense to me and seems a reasonable solution.